# change Video Quality Live tv streaming in android

Tags: android

I want to introduce a feature in which the user can select a tv channel and can see this channel on his mobile device.
 I Use lib vitamio .and blow code:

```
     uri = Uri.parse(path);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mVideoView.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // optional need Vitamio 4.0
        mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
      }
    });
```

his code works properly
.My problem is.
The sites that are online TV.
High quality films.
I want to add a feature that
The quality is low, medium and high.
If the user clicked on low quality, 3gp format broadcast TV online.(For low-speed internet)
It is even possible? What I'm reading
Or ask a stupid question?

Answer (score 0):

```
mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
```

Check this function.